# How to send mail via PHP and/or CakePHP on a Fasthosts account

Tags: php, email, cakephp, smtp

I've had no need to send mails on my 2 sites hosted at the UK Fasthosts provider.
But since I've added some email features to one of my sites I've tried to send mail via the Email Component of CakePHP and it doesn't leave the server, even if the send returns success.

I've tried with plain mail() function and with the smtp option and got nowhere.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can we see your syntax for the mail() function? That should work in almost any shared hosting environment like Fasthosts.

Comment: @James: You can look for it in the Email component of CakePHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem with Fasthosts. They have made it so you have to add `-f` in front of your "sent from" email address so this is what my mail function call looks like:

```
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers, '-f'.$email_from);
```

You can get more info from page on Fasthots help:
http://www.fasthosts.co.uk/knowledge-base/?article_id=65

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with that hosting service but I've had similar experiences with other providers. The one thing that's worked across them all is the SwiftMailer library. Check it out and see if it works for you.

http://swiftmailer.org/

Comment: SwiftMail was my original idea to fix it. I just wanted to know if anyone knew WTF is Fasthosts doing...

Answer (score 0):

Check out SwitfMail (http://swiftmailer.org/). You can connect to most mail systems and send email, no local configuration or dependencies. I regular send alerts through my gmail account.  It's very robust, but has a "simple" execution option if you are not trying to manage email lists.

Comment: I'm familiar with SwiftMail, but would rather want to avoid it and keep CakePHP "insides". I'm basically trying to figure out WTF is Fasthosts doing. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

your code isnt the problem. your email server has alot of queued email. the same issue happend to me with godaddys email server. just give it a day and try again.

Comment: ok, open a new page with nothing on it send a simple mail with the mail function. if it sends then the server is fine. so if thats the case can you post your code?

Comment: Hummm, via command line all looks fine. Will try with script on web server.

Comment: Damn, from a simple script, mail goes. Need to look at CakePHP's code